# julia generate expression with symbol in it

Tags: julia, metaprogramming, symbols

I need to generate an `call` Expr in which one of the keyword arguments is a symbol. I can type it out explicitly like this:

```
julia> dump(:(func(something; a=:b)))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol func
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol parameters
      args: Array{Any}((1,))
        1: Expr
          head: Symbol kw
          args: Array{Any}((2,))
            1: Symbol a
            2: QuoteNode
              value: Symbol b
    3: Symbol something
```

Note the keyword argument `a` which is set to symbol `:b`

What I want to do is generate this expression programmatically where the `:b` part is interpolated from some variable, say `x`.

I tried this

```
julia> x = :u
:u

julia> dump(:(func(something; a=$(x))))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol func
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol parameters
      args: Array{Any}((1,))
        1: Expr
          head: Symbol kw
          args: Array{Any}((2,))
            1: Symbol a
            2: Symbol u
    3: Symbol something
```

but instead of getting a `QuoteNode` with value `Symbol u` I just get the Symbol u. This will not work because when I evaluated the expression, it looks for the variable `u` but it should just be inserting the `Symbol u`. I have tried some other things but can't get it to work.
Thanks

Comment: Just wrap it in a `QuoteNode`  or use `Meta.quot`: `:(func(something; a=$(QuoteNode(x))))`.

Comment: @pfitzseb Make that an answer, the only thing I would add is showing the output of `dump( :(a + :u) )` vs `dump( :(a + u) )` to illustrate the difference.

Comment: @dantheman I will also point out that the interpolation `:(a + $x)` is identical to `Expr(:call, :+, :a, x)`. So you ARE inserting the Symbol `:u` into an expression, it just gets treated as a variable during evaluation like all the other Symbols. So to keep it as a Symbol upon evaluation, you just had to wrap it in QuoteNode. Beware of these intuitive ways of wrapping: `:($x)`, `$(:x)`, and `:x`; they may seem to evaluate as intended, but `dump` will show that you're inserting the Symbol `:x`, not `:u`.

Comment: @pfitzseb Yep, that worked. I could have sworn I tried that but I guess not. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap `x` in a `QuoteNode` manually or use `Meta.quot` (which produces a `Expr(:quote, ...)`):

```
julia> x = :u;

julia> dump(:(func(something; a=$(QuoteNode(x)))))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol func
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol parameters
      args: Array{Any}((1,))
        1: Expr
          head: Symbol kw
          args: Array{Any}((2,))
            1: Symbol a
            2: QuoteNode
              value: Symbol u
    3: Symbol something

julia> func(x; a) = x, a
func (generic function with 1 method)

julia> eval(:(func(something; a=$(QuoteNode(x)))))
(something, :u)

julia> eval(:(func(something; a=$(Meta.quot(x)))))
(something, :u)
```